# Kubernetes - Apply pod affinity rule to live deployment

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I am guess I am just asking for confirmation really. As had some major issues in the past with our elastic search cluster on kubernetes.

Is it fine to add a pod affinity to rule to a already running deployment. This is a live production elastic search cluster and I want to pin the elastic search pods to specific nodes with large storage.
I kind of understand kubernetes but not really elastic search so dont want to cause any production issues/outages as there is no one around that could really help to fix it.

Currently running 6 replicas but want to reduce to 3 that run on 3 worker nodes with plenty of storage.
I have labelled my 3 worker nodes with the label 'priority-elastic-node=true'

This is podaffinity i will add to my yaml file and apply:

```
   podAffinity:
         preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
         - labelSelector:
             matchExpressions:
             - key: priority-elastic-node
               operator: In
               values:
                 - "true"
        topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
```

What I assume will happen is nothing after I apply but then when I start scaling down the elastic node replicas the elastic nodes stay on the preferred worker nodes.

Comment: Since you changed the pod spec, my default assumption would be that Kubernetes would immediately create new pods with the new pod spec and delete the old pods.  In the case of an Elasticsearch cluster, unless you've done some extensive configuration, it wouldn't necessarily pause to re-sync data on to the new pods.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your comment. I really want to avoid the elastic search cluster getting screwed up. In the past its taken days to recover and that was when someone who understood it was here. The other option i was looking at was putting taints on one node at a time as I scale down.

Comment: A [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) might be a better match than a Deployment.  You don't necessarily need its ordering guarantees, but its semantics around updates and backing storage might make more sense here.

Answer (score 1):

Any change to the pod template will cause the deployment to roll all pods. That includes a change to those fields. So it’s fine to change, but your cluster will be restarted. This should be fine as long as your replication settings are cromulent.